# Try Except block not working with datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a DataFrame with some datetime data in one column and whatever else in other columns. However, some of the data is messed up, e.g.:

```
11/11/2014 22:28    15.1
11/11/2014 22:29    16.1
11/11/2014 22:30    15.2
bollocks            10000
11/11/2014 22:32    15.4
:00                 
11/11/2014 22:34    15.3
```

I would like to get rid of the lines that are messed up. For now, I decided to just replace them with NaN values (but dropping them would also help, only it didn't work in the cycle so it's not an issue, in the next step I can just use `dropna()`). I'm doing this using `try()`, but the exception doesn't work. My code looks like this:

```
for line in df.ix[:,"DATETIME"]:    
    try:
        line = datetime.datetime.strptime(line,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    except ValueError:
        line = 'NaN'
    except TypeError:
        line = 'NaN'
```

But in the end, I still get the `ValueError: time data '156004E00F455AA' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'` and the faulty lines are not replaced with `NaN`. What is wrong here? 
(I also tried putting the errors on one line like this: `except (ValueError, TypeError):` and it didn't work either...)

Comment: Are you sure the error is thrown by the bit of code you show? [mcve] please.

Comment: Sorry, this error IS thrown by the bit of code I show, but NOT on the example data. With example data, replace  '156004E00F455AA' with 'bollocks'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) can set to `NaT` ill-formed data while converting the column to datetime.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'], format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')

           DATETIME
0  11/11/2014 22:28
1  11/11/2014 22:29
2  11/11/2014 22:30
3               NaT
4  11/11/2014 22:32
5               NaT
6  11/11/2014 22:34
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't strictly answer your query, but if you are sure that all the valid datetime strings will be of the format: `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"`, you can do:

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
           DATETIME   VALUES
0  11/11/2014 22:28     15.1
1  11/11/2014 22:29     16.1
2  11/11/2014 22:30     15.2
3          bollocks  10000.0
4  11/11/2014 22:32     15.4
5               :00      NaN
6  11/11/2014 22:34     15.3

In [35]: df = df.replace(r'^(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}).*', np.nan, regex=True)

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
           DATETIME   VALUES
0  11/11/2014 22:28     15.1
1  11/11/2014 22:29     16.1
2  11/11/2014 22:30     15.2
3               NaN  10000.0
4  11/11/2014 22:32     15.4
5               NaN      NaN
6  11/11/2014 22:34     15.3

In [37]: df['DATETIME'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
Out[37]: 
0   2014-11-11 22:28:00
1   2014-11-11 22:29:00
2   2014-11-11 22:30:00
3                   NaT
4   2014-11-11 22:32:00
5                   NaT
6   2014-11-11 22:34:00
Name: DATETIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```